# .Net5 backend receives empty JSON

Tags: json, angular, api, http-post, .net-5

I implemented a simple server with .Net5 and an Angular frontend. My api works with post man but only if I set Content-Type equal to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. When I use Content-Type equal to application/json the server receives empty json. When I use my frontend I think I send to server an application/json because it receives the empty one. Below my code.

**api.service.ts**

```js
    public createProva(prova:Iprova): Observable<Iprova> {
        return this.http.post<Iprova>( this.Url, prova );
    }
```

When I console.log *prova* it return a correct Json

**controller.cs**

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("url")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> postProva(provaDto s)
        {
            porvaModel prova = new provaModel
            {
                Id = s.id,
                Name = s.name
            };

            _context.provaModel.Add(prova);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(getProva), new { id = prova.Id }, prova);
        }
```

but  when backend receives provaDto, *s* is empty with *id* equal to *0* and *name* equal to *null*.

Comment: *"When I use Content-Type equal to application-json the server receives empty json."* It's `application/json`, not `application-json`.

Comment: *"When I console.log prova it return a correct Json"* What does that mean? Your type for it is `Iprova`. If it were **JSON**, it would be a string. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript/TypeScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: I see you've changed the question so it uses `application/json` now instead of `application-json`. But did you actually use the right value when you were testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, I assume you have a basic setup for your controller such as this :

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProvaController : ControllerBase
```

I also disable the https redirection in the startup.cs for development purposes, while keeping the default routing functionality.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {     
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        }

        app.UseRouting();            

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

I'll keep the same post method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> postProva(provaDto s)
    {
        porvaModel prova = new provaModel
        {
            Id = s.id,
            Name = s.name
        };

        _context.provaModel.Add(prova);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(getProva), new { id = prova.Id }, prova);
    }
```

As for the Postman setup, I use a POST request on http://localhost:5000/Prova (I use the default launchSettings using dotnet CLI), I also keep default headers. In the Body, I'll use raw and select JSON format, giving it a simple payload :

```
{
"id": 0,
"name": "string"
}
```

As for the angular part, you can specify the content-type of your resquest with the httpOptions :

```
httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  })
};
public createProva(prova:Iprova): Observable<Iprova> {
    return this.http.post<Iprova>( this.Url, prova , this.httpOptions);
}
```